# Azure deploy to a private endpoint-enabled site - scm connection error

Tags: azure, deployment, private, endpoint

I'm following this article in order to deploy the web app on azure with private endpoint: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/01/deploying-to-network-secured-sites-2.html. My understanding is that the access to scm service is not required but is it the case? If I'm wrong, is there any other way to deploy in this case without using VM?

Unfortunately I keep getting the forbidden error:
*An error occured during deployment. Status Code: 403,*

I've tested it from a VM with access to scm and it works fine there but I need to make it work from the machine without the access to scm.

Comment: Can you confirm 443 traffic is not blocked on the VNET where your app service and VM are?  You will need to look at the NSG.

Comment: I've tested it again and apparently it works fine from the machine with access to scm. I've updated the description above. Do I understand correctly that this solution shouldn't require access to scm?